# Stop <a> tag from loading href value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something like this:

```
<a href="http://example.com">
   <span>text</span>
   <button class="hello">hello</button>
</a>
```

When user clicks the `<button>` I don't want the page to go to the href value of the parent `<a>` tag. Is there any way to stop it from redirecting *without* moving the button outside of the anchor tag?

So hooking into the button:

```
jQuery( document ).on( 'click', '.hello', function() {
    // STOP redirect
});
```

What's the solution?

Comment: simply remove the `href`

Comment: @MichelEngelen Read the question.

Comment: I have, but the way you describe it you simply need to remove the `href` from the `a` tag. If you wanted a more sophisticated answer to this you should ask in more detail!

Comment: @MichelEngelen The following in my question is crystal clear: `Is there any way to stop it from redirecting without moving the button outside of the anchor tag? `

Comment: You can use `e.preventDefault();` inside your click event

Comment: @HenrikPetterson and that is exactly what removing the `href` does :D

Comment: While the answers solve your problem, what you are doing is not a correct use of HTML. You cannot put a button into a link, and both elements fulfill different roles. A link is for navigation, a button for actions. If you want your link to look like a button, use CSS to style it instead.

Please read up on the documentation. Two helpful links: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: @MarijkeLuttekes I totally hear you my friend. But I can't adjust the HTML that's outputted by a third-party plugin.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson You should have written that into your question. It would have helped to understand your situation! :(

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Off-topic; Sorry to hear! You could send a message to the people building the plugin regarding this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `e.preventDefault();` to prevent the page on going to href URL.

```js
jQuery(document).on('click', '.hello', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://example.com">
  <span>text</span>
  <button class="hello">hello</button>
</a>
```

Doc: https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: Where do you click it? on the text or the btn?

Comment: `.hello` is only the btn, so this code will only prevent the btn click and not the text.

Comment: It works! Forgot to add `e` in function(). Thanks! Will mark as correct answer shortly.

Comment: Happy to help @HenrikPetterson

Answer (score 1):

So you can do this:

```
<a href="www.example.com">
   <span>text</span>
   <button class="hello" id="btnhello">hello</button>
</a>
```

And then

```
$('#btnhello').onclick((ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault();
  ev.stopPropagation();
});
```

You have the button to call event prevent default so it does not do a submit default behaviour by many browsers, and the event stopPropagation allows not to propagate the event to the parent, the anchor when you click on the button.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this code?

`window.jQuery('.hello').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
      alert("YaY!");
   });`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `preventdefault` - it prevents standard behavior or  you can return false in click function

```
<a href="/" onclick="return false">Press </a>
     or 
<a href="/" onclick="event.preventDefault()">Press </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

ruturn false would stopt it from redirecting it to any other page :

```
jQuery( document ).on( 'click', '.hello', function() {
    // your Code goes here
    // STOP redirect
    return false;
});
```